# Missing Ethereum transaction from Poloniex to MyEtherWallet

Tags: myetherwallet, exchanges, pending-transactions, poloniex

I have sent my transaction from Poloniex to MyEtherWallet and transaction showed up only for ten minutes and after that it disappeared completely without any trace of it.

It didn't return to my original wallet and it didn't come to my new wallet. It just simply disappeared on the system.

I saw many other transactions same thing happening to them on the ether network right after mine!

Here is my TX:

```
0xe0ff12043430c5b3a69d59d7807d41717ba504fcb3b322fc221cce7c1b51102f
```

My wallet address:

```
0xF538e17853a641B986106E2006DEc96a6f0BA0E8
```

Here is a picture of the transaction before it disappeared

> [image: Screenshot of transaction]

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: I have same problem, what i can do for it?

Comment: Same thing happening. Poloniex hasn't responded my ticket yet. Their only announcement regarding this issue has been: "Due to ongoing network instability, we've disabled Ethereum deposits/withdrawals. We'll enable once we know the network is functioning properly." on Twitter. I have 1.99700002 ETH missing, the transaction ID they gave me is 0xccd1d103b105477543acaf4cc464859a6317a9ced7313ff75bb90eecc1f6a32b. But no block explorer finds that TxID. My ether is stuck for over 2 days now, it started during Status token sale